# Highlighting defect/s on a image of toothed wheel

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I'm working on a project where I need to find out if image (toothed wheel) is OK or NOK. It is determined by minimum possible defect (in pixels) of teeth. So far I wrote code which will find the centre of the toothed wheel. From this point given by (x, y) I can "draw" a circle which radius is given as (radius of the toothed wheel - defect given by pixels).

[Image of OK toothed wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji9Vf.jpg)

[Image of NOK toothed wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75iC3.jpg)

I can then extract everything so there are just teeth left. Then I can count them and say that if this value is lower than 19 (which is the number of teeth that toothed wheel have) then its NOK. Otherwise it is OK.

[Circle with prescribed radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrveT.jpg)

[Extracted teeth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzujq.jpg)

My problem now is that I need to highlight these defects on the original image - something like this:

[Highlighted defects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XtPW.jpg)

I have no clue how to do that and would appreciate any help with this problem.

I have this code so far:

```
import math
import cv2

rozmer_kolecka = 12.8 # diameter of a circle in milimeters
velikost_defektu = 0.25 # minimal value of a defect in milimeters

def detect_defects(img):

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    
    contours, hierarchies = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cx = []
    cy = []

    for c in contours:
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        if M['m00'] != 0:
            cx.append(int(M['m10']/M['m00']))
            cy.append(int(M['m01']/M['m00']))

    for i in range(len(cx)):
        cx_hledane = cx[i]
        cy_hledane = cy[i]
        for k in range(len(cx)):
            if (i != k) and ((cx_hledane == cx[k]) or ((cx_hledane - 1) == cx[k]) or ((cx_hledane - 2) == cx[k]) or ((cx_hledane +1) == cx[k]) or ((cx_hledane + 2) == cx[k])):
                if ((cy_hledane == cy[k]) or ((cy_hledane - 1) == cy[k]) or ((cy_hledane - 2) == cy[k]) or ((cy_hledane + 1) == cy[k]) or ((cy_hledane + 2) == cy[k])):
                    hledana_souradnice_x = cx_hledane
                    break

    pomocna = 0
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        M = cv2.moments(contours[i])
        if M['m00'] != 0:
            if hledana_souradnice_x == int(M['m10']/M['m00']):
                kontura = contours[i]

    i = kontura # contour of a toothed wheel
    M = cv2.moments(i)
    if M['m00'] != 0:
        cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00']) # coordinates of the centre of the toothed wheel
        cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        cv2.drawContours(img, [i], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(i)
    cv2.imwrite("ObrysOzubenehoKolecka.jpg", img)

    polomer_kolecka_px = math.ceil(w/2) # radius of the toothed wheel
    pomer = polomer_kolecka_px / (rozmer_kolecka / 2) # ratio: 1 mm in pixels

    img = cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), polomer_kolecka_px - math.ceil(velikost_defektu * pomer) , (0, 0, 255), 1)
    cv2.imwrite("Kruznice_Vada.jpg", img) # Toothed wheel with a radius of defect boundaries

    zoubky = cv2.circle(thresh ,(int(cx),int(cy)), polomer_kolecka_px - math.ceil(velikost_defektu * pomer), 0, -1)
    cv2.imwrite("ZubyOzubenehoKolecka.jpg", zoubky)

    vyrez = zoubky[cy - 150:cy + 150, cx - 150:cx + 150]
    cv2.imwrite("VyrezOzubenehoKolecka.jpg", vyrez) # Extracted teeth
    (cnt, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(vyrez, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    if(len(cnt) < 19):
        print("NOK")
        return False
    else:
        print("OK")
        return True

    cv2.imwrite("image.jpg", img)

obrazek = cv2.imread('Obrazky\\NOK.jpg')
detect_defects(obrazek)
```

Comment: can you add english comments abd varaible names to your code. Would make it much more readable to most of the community

Comment: Tried to comment it a bit in English

Comment: this is a great question.

Comment: there are 2 approaches that one can take.   [1] identify the teeth as you have already correctly done, then identify the short teeth and circle them.   [2] identify expected position of teeth (given that you know the angle) and if there is no tooth, circle this zone.

Comment: Once you have located the center of the gear, convert the image from cartesian to polar coordinates. Here, threshold the image to get a binary mask showing the gear in white. Suppose the image is “unwrapped” horizontally – that is the teeth are now located along the X axis.
Take the sum of every column and locate the peaks – the maximum concentration of white pixels is a tooth. You can get minimum, maximum and average length of the teeth. Further, all “good” teeth extend towards the bottom of the image, as you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/yZ9d335.png).